# Obtener datos de una cadena SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008
Deseo obtener P5

Lo intente de esta manera

```
declare @descripcion varchar(100) = 'P5: HOLA'
select substring(@descripcion, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @descripcion))
```

Pero esta saliendo P5: lo que espero es P5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más fácil y confiable es usar un cero para el segundo parámetro. Así evitas errores de valores negativos en el tercer parámetro en caso de que no se encuentre el caracter indicado.

```
declare @descripcion varchar(100) = 'P5: HOLA'
select substring(@descripcion, 0, CHARINDEX(':', @descripcion))
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia de `1` por `0` y ahora si no muestre los dos puntos?

Comment: El uno indica que toma desde el primer caracter, el cero indica que empieza un caracter antes. Si pusieras un número negativo, regresaría menos caracteres aún.